# Can I make an alias to override "git pull" on a single local repo?

Tags: git, alias

I am working on a local Git repo where the canonical upstream repo lives in a Git/SVN limbo. Because of this, pushing and pulling from Git requires a special sequence of commands rather than simply "git push" and "git pull". (I do not control the upstream repo so I cannot change this.) However, sometime I forget and attempt the regular commands, messing up my local repo and sometimes having to redo work. (Luckily, the remote repo is impervious.)

I have found tips on creating new git subcommands via alias (frex, "git co" for "git checkout"). Can I set a git alias to override existing, standard git commands like "push" and "pull"? Can I do this for only the weird repo, not all repos on my machine?

I would be happy to alias to `echo "You can't do that."`

Comment: You can't override existing commands, but you could create something like a `git pull-special` command for that repo. If you really wanted to override it, you could create a bash alias to a function. You'd have to work out some logic to ensure it was only that repo though.

Comment: You can override the git pull/push commands in yout .bashrc file but it will be global. If you want it only for specific repo yout best bet is adding pre-pull and pre-push hooks.

Answer (score 0):

If the sepcial sequence of commands have equivalent git configurations, you can probably check if it possible to set them in in your weird-repo/.git/config file. This link specifies possible configuration options http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.
Otherwise, you still can write a custom-git.sh script and alias it as a replacement for git. In that script, you execute the special commands if you are working on your weird-repo or fallback to standard git if not.